# PHP, MySQL Query Always Returning 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I know I have more than one result in the table, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("x","y","z");
if (!$con)
{
die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
$query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersonline WHERE datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the aggregate COUNT() function without a GROUP BY clause. It'll collapse the entire result set down and count the number of records, so all you'll ever get back is a  1-row-with-1-field result set.

Answer (score 5):

The result of `mysql_num_rows` *will* be one, you're only selecting one row from the database, it just happens to be the count of records that match a condition. Try this:

```
$query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM usersonline WHERE datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_rows = $row['cnt'];
echo $num_rows;
```